# refresh classes created with ng-class

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build an embedded calendar object using Angular 1 and Bootstrap.
I have this line of code to show the days in the week:

```
<span class="day" ng-class="{ today: day.isToday, 'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, selected: day.date.isSame(selected), available: day.isAvailable }" ng-repeat="day in week.days">{{day.number}}</span>
```

and day.isAvailable is set correctly the first month:
[first month correct highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWY4a.png)

however following months highlighting is wrong and I can't figure out why
[month+1 wrong highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNJb.png)

```
isAvailable: daysAvailable.indexOf(date.format("dd").substring(0, 2)) > -1,
```

I am willing to update with other code that may be nessesary to answer

Comment: ng-class is dynamic, so something isn't evaluating as you expect. I'd put the ng-class logic into a function so you can trace it.

Comment: It seems like you would want the ng repeat in a div above the span if you are going to reference the day object in the span.  I may be missing what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Can you explain what this part of your code is doing? `ng-class="{ today: day.isToday, 'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, selected: day.date.isSame(selected), available: day.isAvailable }"`. Ng-class should have an expression or a function. What I see is that you are using it to set some local variables. Can you tell us which are your classes and which are your objects in there?

Comment: that part of my code is setting several classes based upon evaluation.
today: day.isToday sets <span class="today"> if day is today
selected: day.date.isSame(selected) sets <span class="selected"> if day is selected

Comment: the classes are: today, different-month, selected, available

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you are using ng-class correctly. Please, read de docs to see how it works.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

EDIT

Based in the answer you gave me in the comments, I ended up qith this solution:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.week = {
    days: [
      new day(2016, 04, 15, false),
      new day(2016, 04, 16, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 17, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 18, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 19, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 20, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 21, false),
      new day(2016, 04, 22, false),
      new day(2016, 04, 23, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 24, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 25, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 26, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 27, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 28, false),
      new day(2016, 04, 29, false),
      new day(2016, 04, 30, true),
      new day(2016, 04, 31, true),
      new day(2016, 05, 01, true),
      new day(2016, 05, 02, true),
      new day(2016, 05, 03, true),
      new day(2016, 05, 04, false)
    ]
  };
  $scope.selectDay = function(d){
    $scope.selected = d;
  }
}]);
  
function day(year, month, day, avaiable){
  var self = this;
  self.date = new Date(year, month, day);
  self.isAvailable = avaiable;
  self.number = self.date.getDate();
  self.isCurrentMonth = isCurrentMonth(self.date);
  self.isToday = isToday(self.date);
};

function isToday(date){
    var d = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
      && date.getMonth() === d.getMonth()
      && date.getDate() === d.getDate();
  }

function isCurrentMonth(date){
    var d = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
      && date.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
}

Date.prototype.isSame = function(d){
  if(!d){
    return false;
  } else {
    return this.getFullYear() === d.date.getFullYear()
    && this.getMonth() === d.date.getMonth()
    && this.getDate() === d.date.getDate();
  }
}
```

```css
.day{
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
}

.today{
  background: orange !Important;
}

.different-month{
  background: #e5e5e5 !Important;
}

.selected{
  background: yellow !Important;
}

.available{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myAppController">

    <span 
          class="day" 
          ng-class="{ 
                    'today': day.isToday,
                    'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth,
                    'selected': day.date.isSame(selected),
                    'available': day.isAvailable
                    }"
          ng-repeat="day in week.days"
          ng-click="selectDay(day)"
    >{{day.number}}</span>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It'd be nice to tell him specifically what you think is wrong.

Comment: I did in the comments below his question. But I'll edit this answer putting that comment in it. Thanks @MikeFeltman